# handle not authorized to OpenID connect policy?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I am following this wiki [Quickstart: Add sign-in with Microsoft to an ASP.NET Core web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp)

I have a policy like this :

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CanAccessAdminGroup",
        policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireClaim("groups", "Guid"));
});
```

My controller is decorated with `[Authorize(Policy = "CanAccessAdminGroup")]`

Which works ok when user is in this AAD group.
But when user is not in group, i get sent to `xxx/Account/AccessDenied?returnurl=xx`

How do I change the redirect to use a different controller/action, like   `/identity/index` ?

I tried to this but did not work:

```
OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
{
    context.Response.Redirect("Identity/Index");
    context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception
    return Task.CompletedTask;
```

This is the output from Debug window:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization failed.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ForbidResult:Information: Executing ForbidResult with authentication schemes ().
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: AzureADCookie was forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

You can firstly create an authorization requirement :

```
public class MatchGroupRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public String  GroupID { get; }

    public MatchGroupRequirement(string groupID)
    {
        GroupID = groupID;
    }
}
```

Create an authorization handler which is  responsible for the evaluation of a requirement's properties , in custom authorization you can redirect to any desired controller action using the `AuthorizationFilterContext` and with the `RedirectToActionResult` :

```
public class MatchGroupHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MatchGroupRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                    MatchGroupRequirement requirement)
    {
        var redirectContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;
        var groups = context.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "groups").ToList();
            var matchingvalues = groups.Where(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Value.Contains(requirement.GroupID)).FirstOrDefault();
        //check the condition 
        if (matchingvalues == null)
        {
            redirectContext.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("identity", "index", null);
            context.Succeed(requirement);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Policy and handler registration :

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("MatchGroup", policy =>
        policy.Requirements.Add(new MatchGroupRequirement("ddf1ad17-5052-46ba-944a-7da1d51470b0")));
});

services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MatchGroupHandler>();
```

Applying policies to MVC controllers/Actions :

```
[Authorize(Policy = "MatchGroup")]
public IActionResult Contact()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

    return View();
}
```

Comment: hi Nan,
can you educate me a little ? why can't i  use my existing  [Authorize(Policy and configure a redirect ? I found a 13 page guide  but i want to 
 understand the reason before i jump in (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Thanks, Peter

Comment: Your `OnAuthenticationFailed` fires in openid connect authentication , but the policy authentication fires after openid connect authentication .  That means your Azure AD login success, but in your application , the policy failed because there is no match group claim in claim principle . So set redirect in OIDC evens won't work in this scenario .

Comment: thanks for explaining!!!   I am focused on my business application - just want  something simple. I prefer not to write more authentication code unless necessary.  After   Policy authentication fails (because I am not in the AAD group), i get redirected  https://myapp/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2FReservations    <-- what about creating  a controller called account with action accessDenied? Curious where is Account/AccessDenied  is configured?
Thanks a ton, Peter

Comment: You can create `AccountController` and `AccessDenied` action and relate view .